# tastypie saving foreignkey field throws exception

Tags: python, django, tastypie, restful-architecture

I'm trying to add the foreign key to my tastypie resources, but django throws out this error:

```
"error_message": "'BB' object is not iterable",
```

I've created a minimal working example:

**models.py**

```
class AA(models.Model):
    n = models.IntegerField()


class BB(models.Model):
    aa = models.ForeignKey(AA, related_name='xox')
    t = models.CharField(max_length=2)
```

**resources.py**

```
from ..models import AA, BB

from tastypie.authorization import Authorization
from tastypie.fields import ForeignKey


class AResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = AA.objects.all()
        authorization = Authorization()


class BBResource(ModelResource):
    aa = ForeignKey(AResource, 'aa', related_name="xox", full=False, blank=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        queryset = BB.objects.all()
        authorization = Authorization()
```

Now using curl to perform the post action:

```
$ curl -XPOST --dump-header - --header 'Content-Type: application/json' localhost:8000/api/v1/a/ --data '{"n": 18}'
$ curl -XPOST --dump-header - --header 'Content-Type: application/json' localhost:8000/api/v1/bb/ --data '{"t": "di", "aa": "/api/v1/a/1/"}'
```

**Traceback:**

```
 {
    "error_message": "'BB' object is not iterable", 
    "traceback": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n\n  File \"/home/mee/.venvs/env_pro/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 219, in wrapper\n    response = callback(request, *args, **kwargs)\n\n  File \"/home/mee/.venvs/env_pro/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 450, in dispatch_list\n    return self.dispatch('list', request, **kwargs)\n\n  File \"/home/mee/.venvs/env_pro/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 482, in dispatch\n    response = method(request, **kwargs)\n\n  File \"/home/mee/.venvs/env_pro/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 1384, in post_list\n    updated_bundle = self.obj_create(bundle, **self.remove_api_resource_names(kwargs))\n\n  File \"/home/mee/.venvs/env_pro/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 2175, in obj_create\n    return self.save(bundle)\n\n  File \"/home/mee/.venvs/env_pro/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 2322, in save\n    self.save_related(bundle)\n\n  File \"/home/mee/.venvs/env_pro/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 2382, in save_related\n    setattr(related_obj, field_object.related_name, bundle.obj)\n\n  File \"/home/mee/.venvs/env_pro/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py\", line 481, in __set__\n    manager.set(value)\n\n  File \"/home/mee/.venvs/env_pro/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py\", line 639, in set\n    objs = tuple(objs)\n\nTypeError: 'BB' object is not iterable\n"
}
```

**Package versions:**

```
Django==1.9.7
django-tastypie==0.13.3
```

**EDIT**

By querying the bb objects I can see the association is being stored

```
$  curl localhost:8000/api/v1/bb/
{
"meta": {
    "limit": 20, 
    "next": null, 
    "offset": 0, 
    "previous": null, 
    "total_count": 1
}, 
"objects": [
    {
        "aa": "/api/v1/a/1/", 
        "id": 1, 
        "resource_uri": "/api/v1/bb/1/", 
        "t": "di"
    }
]
```

And by inspecting the traceback, the error is raised in the django code.

Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was a simple (and newbie) question that make me feel like a déjà vu. The issue here is to remember when to use `related_name`, in this case that param isn't necessary.

[Link to the docs](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fields.html#related-name) where the `related_name` param is explained.